# Help with rewriting two expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with the following task and would appreciate some help with solving it, any help would be much appreciated.

Let:
$$x_1=\frac{m}{p_1+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}}$$
$$x_2=\frac{m}{\sqrt{p_1·p_2}+p_2}$$

Show that:
$$-(\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2})=-(\sqrt{p_1}+\sqrt{p_2})^2·\frac{1}{m}$$

Thanks in advance for any help,
Mathias

Comment: We have trouble with your question.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question to tell us what the "two expressions" are, what rewriting them means, and your efforts to answer the question yourself. That's the only way to get help here.

Comment: Sorry i had trouble with mathjax, i've fixed the equations.

Comment: Hint: if $x=\frac{a}{b}$ then $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{b}{a}$.

Comment: @MathiasSchrøderArendrup If you are given that $\,p_1,p_2 \gt 0\,$ then you should state so in the question.

Comment: In the future, if you are having trouble with a problem, tell us what *part* of the problem you are having trouble in. Perhaps you are trying to work things out but you have calculated or equated the steps incorrectly. Unless you have made no attempt at all in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested solution is true if only $p_1$ AND $p_2$ are both positive. (As @dxiv mentioned) Otherwise, you should include abstract under the radicals.

i.e. $\displaystyle (\frac {1}{x_1} + \frac {1}{x_2})=\frac{-1}{m}(\sqrt {|p_1|}+\sqrt{|p_2|})^2$

Here is the solution:

$\displaystyle x_1=\frac{m}{p_1+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}} \to \frac{1}{x_1}=\frac{p_1+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}}{m}$

$\displaystyle x_2=\frac{m}{p_2+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}} \to \frac{1}{x_2}=\frac{p_2+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}}{m}$

$\displaystyle \to \frac {1}{x_1} + \frac {1}{x_2}=\frac{p_1+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}}{m} + \frac{p_2+\sqrt{p_1·p_2}}{m} =  \frac{p_1+p_2+2\sqrt{p_1p_2}}{m}=\frac{\sqrt {p_1^2}+\sqrt{p_2^2}+2\sqrt{p_1p_2}}{m}=\frac{(\sqrt {p_1}+\sqrt{p_2})^2}{m}$

$\displaystyle  \to -(\frac {1}{x_1} + \frac {1}{x_2})=\frac{-1}{m}(\sqrt {p_1}+\sqrt{p_2})^2$